# Shinobi Charts iOS -> custom crosshair behavior, custom tick on axis for selected data point, drawing on the chart

Tags: ios, charts, shinobi

Currently I am trying out the ShinobiCharts. I am hoping that they will meet the requirements for the App the company I work at is making.
In this app there has to be the possibility to track the curves in the chart. I have some questions:

1. Can i add a custom tick on the xAxis that marks the selected point onto it( something like the line from the crosshair but with a label with the value on the axis)? I recall a chart made with ShinobiCharts online somewhere with that functionality but just can't find it in the API.
2. The crosshair seems to draw a handy "target circle". Can I draw those circles on demand at a given chart point?
3. The crosshair seems to be a thing we want... well almoust. It should draw those targets on a couple of the curves and track them along the drawn series (not just one). Can that be done?
4. Amongst thart can the crosshair behaviour be overrided - so that it will be movable only when te first long tap is made and after that the chart is pannable again. The crosshair can be then dragged again after another long tap.

Will be rateful for any help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this tutorial. It doesn't answer all your questions but it helps:

http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2012/07/19/customizing-that-crosshair/